# Taylor series expansion example

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I was reading an article and there was a snippet with a taylor series expansion as shown below:

[image]

My question is, should (11) read as $F(xA+h)+(xΔA+Δh)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(xA+h)$ instead of what is listed? If not, can someone explain?

Comment: I guess you are right in your statement